# Convert type List<Object> to Object

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Up
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string oft { get; set; }
}
```

and I am calling the following function:

```
private Up GetUp()
    {
        var json = _fileSystem.File.ReadAllText(localPath);
        var cur = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Up>>(json);
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", current)); 
        return cur;
    }
```

This gives an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Up>' to 'Up'.
```

I am trying to return one object with multiple values so I can iterate over them. Is this even possible what I am trying to do here? (fairly new to C#).

Comment: Your method signature: `private Up GetUp()` -> you've stated that you're returning a single `Up`. How does this differ to what you're actually returning?

Comment: `cur` is a list of `Up` objects (as long as everything else is actually functioning as expected). So you should be able to get the first `Up` like so `var firstUp = cur[0];`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar the json file is an array of multiple key, value pairs. So, isn't this function returning list of objects rather than one object?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 But I want it to return a list of objects, why won't it let me return that?

Comment: Oh, then refer to @DiplomacyNotWar first comment. Review your method signature, you want it to return a `List<Up>` but it is currently defined to return a single `Up`.

Comment: Your JSON isn't the problem. In writing `private Up GetUp()`, you have stated to the compiler "my method returns a single Up". Any callers expect to get a single `Up`. The compiler expects the method excepts you to return a single `Up`. `cur` is not a single `Up`, it is a `List<Up>`. The solution is to make the method return what you says it does, or fix the method so it states that it's returning what you're actually returning.

Comment: Holy shit, I am stupid! thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a method, its method signature defines the expected return type (among other things). The error you are seeing is letting you know that you currently have a `System.Collections.Generic.List<Up>`, but it (the compiler) was expecting `Up` to be returned by the method.

You are currently defining your method as:

`private Up GetUp()`

Which is telling the compiler that you want to define a method named `GetUp`, which is a `private` method, and which returns an `Up` object.

You probably want it's return type to be a `List<Up>`:

`private List<Up> GetUp()`